# Connecting R from JSP

Tags: r, jsp, driver

I am building a web interface where user can write a text. I need to analyse the user input text with R script. 
Is there a driver to connect R and JSP?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I manage to do this with RESTful web services. I can use the same driver for java (Rserve) now.